# Disabling Font Awesome Icon

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, font-awesome

I am building a search bar which I want to be disabled unless the user enters something. Appreciate any help to make this work.

This is my handlebars code:

```
<div class="searchWrapper">
        <form action="/founduser" method="POST" class="searchBar">
            <input type="hidden" id="groupid" name="groupid" value={{this.groupid}}>
            <input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="Enter the user's email ID"
                value="{{this.term}}" />
            {{!-- <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <input type="submit" value="" id="submit"> --}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn-search" id="user-search-btn"><span class="icon search"
                    disabled></span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and I am running a JS check to alternate

```
const searchButton = document.getElementById('user-search-btn');
    const check = () => {
        if (searchButton !== "") {
            searchButton.disabled = false
        } else {
            searchButton.disabled = true
        }
    }
    searchButton.onkeyup = check
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `searchButton` is an element, what are you trying to compare to a string for?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured where I was going wrong. In my code I was checking if `searchButton` was empty, however what I should have done was to check the value inside the `<input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="Enter the user's email ID" value="{{this.term}}" />`.